# Flutter Gridview not updating values from firebase

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. I am building a app with firebase. In my app I want show product details in gridview. The details are taken from firebase. I am getting the value successfully. But the value I got from the firebase where not updating to GridView list. My code is shown below.

**AppMain.Dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:augr/location/LocationScreen.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  MyApp({this.firestore});
  final Firestore firestore;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'My Shop', firestore: firestore)
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.firestore}) : super(key: key);
  final Firestore firestore;
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState(firestore: firestore);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  _MyHomePageState({this.firestore});
  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.black, //change font color here
    ),
    backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
        )
            title:"title",
      body: TheGridview().build(),
    );
  }
  }

class TheGridview{
  Card makeGridCell(String name, IconData icon){
    return Card(
      elevation: 1.0,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Icon(icon)),
            Text(name)
          ],
        ),
    );
  }

  GridView build(){
    return GridView.count(
      primary: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,

      children: createChildrenTexts(),

    /*  children: <Widget>[
        makeGridCell("Home", Icons.access_alarm)
      ],*/


    );
  }

  List<Widget> createChildrenTexts(){
    List<Widget> childrenTexts = List<Widget>();


    getProduceID().then((data){
      for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){

         childrenTexts.add(makeGridCell(data[i].data['message'], Icons.access_alarm));
        print("data from firebase:"+data[i].data['message']);

      }
    });

    return childrenTexts;
  }

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getProduceID() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("messages").getDocuments();
    var list = querySnapshot.documents;
    return list;
  }
}
```

The `createChildrenTexts` is the method I want to add items in GridView. The from firebase is printing in console. But not adding in list. I know I want to write in stateful widget. But I how to write please help me.

Comment: Why your for loop running from value 0 to 1 and not to data.length ?

Comment: It's for data.length. I am sorry for that. I changed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer when I added `createChildrenTexts` inside the `_MyHomePageState` class. So I can access the data from the Firestore. And I declare array `documents` in `_MyHomePageState` . Then also added a flag `isDocLoaded` for checking the value is stored or not. My final code is shown below.

```
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:augr/location/LocationScreen.dart';
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.

    MyApp({this.firestore});
    final Firestore firestore;


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'My Shop', firestore: firestore)
      );
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.firestore}) : super(key: key);
    final Firestore firestore;
    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState(firestore: firestore);
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    _MyHomePageState({this.firestore});
    final Firestore firestore;

    var documents = [];
    bool isDocLoaded=false;


    void initState() {
      Firestore.instance.collection("messages").getDocuments().then((data) async {
        var list = data.documents;
        documents = list;
        print("init state document:" +
            documents.length.toString()); // value is getting
        super.initState();
        setState(() {
          isDocLoaded = true;
          documents = list;
        });
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black, //change font color here
          ),
          backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
        )
        title:"title",
        body: isDocLoaded? TheGridview():Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }

    Widget TheGridView(){
      return GridView.count(
        primary: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,

        children: createChildrenTexts(),

        /*  children: <Widget>[
              makeGridCell("Home", Icons.access_alarm)
            ],*/
      );
    }

    Card makeGridCell(String name, IconData icon){
      return Card(
        elevation: 1.0,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Icon(icon)),
            Text(name)
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    List<Widget> createChildrenTexts(){
      print("createChildrenTexts:"+documents.length.toString()); // the value getting 0
      List<Widget> childrenTexts = List<Widget>();
      for(int i=0;i<documents.length;i++){
        childrenTexts.add(makeGridCell(makeGridCell(data[i].data['message'], Icons.access_alarm));
        }
            return createchildwidget;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to fetch data from firebase for a build method call. Remember in reactive programming approach you do the network stuffs separate from the build method and put the data returned from the network call in the state. On every state change, the framework re-draws the frame.

Below code might help you but I highly recommend you to read [this](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs) thoroughly.

1. Declare a documents variable at the state class

   `var documents = [];`
2. Call firestore from initState function and update the documents value using setState() function

   `void initState() {
     super.initState();
     Firestore.instance.collection("messages").getDocuments().then((data){
         var list = data.documents;
         setState((){
           documents = list;
         });
     });
   }`
3. Use the documents variable to loop over and render the data

   ```
   List<Widget> createChildrenTexts(){
     List<Widget> childrenTexts = List<Widget>();
     for(int i=0;i<documents.length;i++){ 
       childrenTexts.add(makeGridCell(documents[i].data['message'], Icons.access_alarm));
       print("data from firebase:"+documents[i].data['message']);  
     }
     return childrenTexts;
   }
   ```

Comment: In initState() when I add QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("messages").getDocuments(); It showing error "A value of type 'Future<QuerySnapshot>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'QuerySnapshot'"

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: You can only use await keyword on an async function and initState cant be made an async function. Use the .then method in getDocuments function to receive data.

Comment: when I am using the above code. It is not entering in "setState(()". The "createChildrenTexts()" getting the document list is zero. I extend the class TheGridview with _MyHomePageState. In void initState() it is taking data from firebase.

Comment: I called initState in _MyHomePageState.

Comment: documents is showing 0 in class TheGridview extends _MyHomePageState{}. But in initState() showing as 18.

Comment: Is there any solution?